# The functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)+\frac{x+y-1}{xy}$ with a hint of differentiability

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

Okay so I got this question in a rehearsal test today, and got completely stumped.

Let $f$ be a differentiable function satisfying the functional rule $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)+\frac{x+y-1}{xy}$, $\forall$ $x,y>0$ and $f'(1)=2$.The question asked some more questions regarding $f(x)$,but I am unable to find $f(x)$.

**My try**:*I tried to treat $y$ as a constant and then differentiated both sides of the equation,making use of the fact that $f'(1)=2$ ; but that got me nowhere.Someone kindly help.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try substituting y=1/x and the differentiate

Comment: How does that help ?

Answer (score 5):

Your try gives

$$yf'(xy) = f'(x) -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2y},\tag{1}$$

for all $x,y > 0$. Choosing $x = 1$ in $(1)$, we obtain

$$yf'(y) = 2 - 1 + \frac{1}{y},$$

or

$$f'(y) = \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2}.\tag{2}$$

From that, we can easily determine $f$ up to addition of a constant, and we can determine the constant from the rule e.g. by setting $x = y = 1$ there.

An alternative way to find the function is to rewrite the functional equation as

$$f(xy) + \frac{1}{xy} = \biggl(f(x) + \frac{1}{x}\biggr) + \biggl(f(y) + \frac{1}{y}\biggr),$$

and if one knows the continuous functions satisfying the functional equation $g(xy) = g(x) + g(y)$, $f$ is easily determined.

Comment: Sorry , Thanks for your effort into this , but like a noob I am ,Im not getting anything.How do i get $f(x)$ from this ? And how do I tackle similar problems?Isnt there a thumb rule?

Comment: We have a nice form for the derivative of $f$. One can read the primitives of $f'$ off that if one knows the derivatives of the most famous functions. If $g'(y) = y^{\alpha}$, what is $g(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{f}}$ is differentiable.
>   $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{xy} = \,\mrm{f}\pars{x} + \,\mrm{f}\pars{y} + {1 \over y} +
> {1 \over x} - {1 \over xy}\,,\quad
> x, y \in \mathbb{R}_{\ >\ 0}\quad\mbox{and}\quad\mrm{f}'\pars{1} = 2}$.

$$
\bbx{\quad\mbox{Note that}\quad\mrm{f}\pars{1} = -1\quad
\pars{~\mbox{from the 'original functional equation'}~}\quad}
$$

- Derive both members, of the above functional equation, respect of $\ds{x}$:
  \begin{equation}
  \mrm{f}'\pars{xy}y =
  \,\mrm{f}'\pars{x} - {1 \over x^{2}} + {1 \over x^{2}y}
  \implies
  \mrm{f}'\pars{xy}xy =
  \,\mrm{f}'\pars{x}x - {1 \over x} + {1 \over xy}
  \label{1}\tag{1}
  \end{equation}
- Derive both members, of the above functional equation, respect of $\ds{y}$:
  \begin{equation}
  \mrm{f}'\pars{xy}x =
  \,\mrm{f}'\pars{y} - {1 \over y^{2}} + {1 \over xy^{2}}
  \implies
  \mrm{f}'\pars{xy}xy =
  \,\mrm{f}'\pars{y}y - {1 \over y} + {1 \over xy}
  \label{2}\tag{2}
  \end{equation}
  \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} lead to:
  \begin{align}
  &\,\mrm{f}'\pars{x}x - {1 \over x} = \,\mrm{f}'\pars{y}y - {1 \over y} = \alpha\,,
  \qquad\pars{~\alpha:\ \mbox{a}\ x\ \mbox{and}\ y\ \mbox{independent constant}~}
  \end{align}

  > $\ds{\alpha = \,\mrm{f}'\pars{1} \times 1 - {1 \over 1} = 1}$.

Now, you are left with
$$
\,\mrm{f}'\pars{x} = {1 \over x} + {1 \over x^{2}}\,,\quad\mrm{f}\pars{1} = -1
\implies \bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x} = \ln\pars{x} - {1 \over x}}}
$$